# Javascript runtime error 'Show' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to display a loading gif while my datatable is being loaded on my server.
I found some code from [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-loading-image-while-PostBack-calls-in-ASPNet.aspx), but when i try and implement it I get the Runtime error 'Show' is undefined. Below is my javascript/jquery code i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowProgress() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var modal = $('<div />');
        modal.addClass("modal");
        $('body').append(modal);
        var loading = $(".loading");
        loading.show();
        var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
        var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
        loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
    }, 200);
}
$('form').live("submit", function () {
    ShowProgress();
});
```

My div id is loading, so when it encounters the loading.show() in the javascript, it errors out.

```
<div class="loading" align="center">
    Loading. Please wait.<br />
         <br />
         <img src="gears.gif" alt="" />
        </div>
```

And I am registering my script on the page load event like:

```
 If IsPostBack = False Then
        Dim script As String = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=Button2]').click(); });"
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "load", script, True)

    End If
```

**EDIT:**
I am editing it to add the Css markup as well.

```
<style type="text/css">
.modal
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.loading
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: White;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey there, when is the div.loading rendered? I'm guessing you add it to the DOM, after the submit button. Do you have it style to be hidden, and the show() it to the user, or you have it dynamically created, if this so make it hidden. Hope it helps

Comment: Krum, i edited my post, showing my Css markup. The loading div is after the grid that i am going to be updating with my datatable once built. the button is towards the top of the page.

Comment: Try this loading.css( "display", "block" ) if it is already hidden. Also post the console error that you are seeing.

Comment: praveen, i tried you suggestion and it seems to work. note that i also changed some code on the server side and everything seems to be displaying correctly now! thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out the problem I was having, apparently I had a piece of code stuck in the code behind that was from an earlier experiment that was some how referencing me to the location.show(). 
Once I took out the below code everything started working.

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "show();", True)
```

thanks to everyone that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The example you're referencing is using Bootstrap.  You need to reference the bootstrap javascript library in your code to use the `.show()` method.

Here's the topmost part of the example's source code - see the bottom line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /><title>
    Display Loading progress Image when Page loads or does PostBack using ASP.Net
</title><meta http-equiv="Keywords" content="Mudassar,Mudassar Khan, Mudassar Ahmed Khan,asp.net articles,C#.NET Articles,ASP,ASP.NET,C#,VB,CSharp,C Sharp,dotnet,GridView,DropDownList,Visual Studio,AJAX,CSS, CSS3, JavaScript,JQuery,XML,Crystal Reports,SSIS,SSRS,DetailsView,winforms,windows forms,windows application,code samples,.net code examples,WCF tutorial,WebService tutorial,LINQ,,authoring,programming,learning,beginners guide,primer,lessons,school,howto,reference,free,examples,samples,source code,demos,tips,links,FAQ,tag list,forms,Crystal Reports,Reporting,RDLC Reports,ReportViewer,FaceBook,Twiiter,Google, Google Maps" /><meta http-equiv="Description" content="
ASP.NET,C#.NET,VB.NET,JQuery, Json,JavaScript,Gridview,SQL Server,Ajax,jQuery Plugins,jQuery UI,SSRS,RDLC,Crystal Reports,Reports,FaceBook, Twitter, Google, Google Maps, API, Windows Forms, Windows, WinForms, XML,HTML, CSS, CSS3, jQuery demos,code,snippets, examples, articles" /><link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Free ASP.Net Code Snippets, Tutorials, Articles, Technical Stuff, Tips, Solutions and much more. | ASP.Net, C#.Net, VB.Net, AJAX,JQuery, JavaScript, GridView,SQL Server, RDLC, SSRS, Crystal Reports, XML, JSON, FaceBook, Twitter, Google Maps examples" href="/RSS.axd" /><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//aspsnippets.com/images/Metro/Blue/ASPSmall.png" /><meta content="Mudassar Ahmed Khan" name="author" /><meta content="index,follow" name="robots" /><meta content="index, follow" name="Googlebot" />


    <!--[if gt IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Demos/Bootstrap-3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/Bootstrap-3.0/css/override.css?15_12_2016" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" media="screen" />
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/Bootstrap-3.0/media/Above_1024.css?06_05_2014" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 767px)" href="//aspsnippets.com/Demos/Bootstrap-3.0/media/below_767.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]>                
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//aspsnippets.com/Demos/Bootstrap-3.0/media/Above_1024.css?06_05_2014" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 767px)" href="//aspsnippets.com/Demos/Bootstrap-3.0/media/below_767.css" /> 
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//aspsnippets.com/Demos/Bootstrap-3.0/css/IE.css?06_05_2014" />
        <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Xavier, I do not see anywhere on that example where they are saying you need to use Bootstrap. Could you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: You are correct... The website he is posting on is using bootstrap, but the example code that he shared is not. if you search for bootstrap in his example project there is none there, but if you open the website page source yes there is some there..

Comment: And that's why `.show()` is not working, as OP states in the post.  It clearly reads "'Show' is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

Remove below line from your loading class css

```
display:none;
```

And use below JS line at the begining of your JS script as an alternative to `display:none;` in CSS

```
(".loading").hide();
```

Comment: Munadil, I tried your suggested change and i am still getting the error. The div is also not displaying now when I use the #loading instead of the .loading. in the past the div will display for a few seconds, and then i will receive the error.

Comment: Hi, I have changed my answer as loading is actually a class in your code. Please try as I mentioned in the above answer.